# В чем отличия методов ввода строки (чисел) Python?

Tags: python, строки, числа, ввод

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем отличия между:

```
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

Работают они одинаково, но мне бы хотелось знать, есть ли случаи, в которых нужно использовать тот или иной вариант ввода?

Comment: Ни в чём. . . .

Comment: Второй вариант считается более предпочтительным, потому что легче читается и является более явным

Comment: @MaxU функциональщики обидятся и возразят)

Comment: @andreymal, [“pep-202: List comprehensions provide a more concise way to create lists in situations where map() and filter() and/or nested loops would currently be used.”](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) ;)

Comment: @MaxU данная цитата говорит только о краткости, но не о том что это лучший вариант. Предпоследний пример по ссылке ИМХО вообще демонстрация того как не нужно делать - лучше уж просто два обычных вложенных цикла использовать.